# Why can geom_path not be coloured when used together with plotly in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly, ggplotly

I have a shiny app with `server.R` and `ui.R`.

This is the code in `server.R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

dat=data.frame(mycolA=c(1,2,3,4), mycolB=c(12,13,16,10), mycolC=c(330,510,290,530))

    p=ggplot(dat,aes(x=mycolB, y=mycolC)) +
    geom_path(aes(colour=mycolA)) # <----------------------------------
    #geom_path() 

    output$myggplotwithplotly=renderPlotly({
    p
    })

    output$myggplotonly=renderPlot({
        p
    })

})
```

This is the code in `ui.R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ui <- shinyUI(fillPage(
fillRow(
plotlyOutput("myggplotwithplotly", height="100%"), plotOutput("myggplotonly", height="100%")
  )

))
```

It returns:

[image: Why is there no line in the left diagram?]

As you see, there is no line in the plotly-diagram on the left.

If I use `geom_path()` instead of `geom_path(aes(colour=mycolA))` in `server.R` then I get:

[image]

**My Question:** Why is the coloured line not displayed in plotly and how do I need to change the code to display it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it might not be possible yet. When you trying to convert your `ggplot` code to `plot_ly` using: `plot_ly(dat, x = ~mycolB, y = ~mycolC, color = ~mycolA, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")`, I get the warning: "Numeric color variables cannot (yet) be mapped to lines.
 when the trace type is 'scatter' or 'scattergl'."

Comment: I suggest opening a request on github.

Comment: @masoud done that.

Comment: x-ref: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1294